# How to use nodejs Assert

Tags: node.js

How to use the Assert in nodejs http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Tried

```
Assert.assert(1===1);
```

It throws following error

```
ReferenceError: Assert is not defined
```

How to use "assert". I am new to javascript and nodejs. The nodejs documentation explictly mentions some of the sections as a class Example:- http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_buffer_1. But Assert is not mentioned as a class. Then what is "Assert"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This module is used for writing unit tests for your applications, you can access it with `require('assert')`.

```
var assert = require('assert');

assert.throws(
  function() {
    throw new Error("Wrong value");
  },
  function(err) {
    if ( (err instanceof Error) && /value/.test(err) ) {
      return true;
    }
  },
  "unexpected error"
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Although assert is already included in nodejs installation. You still need to require it.

```
var assert = require('assert')
```

And then use as follows:

```
assert.equal(1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assert.throws(
  function() {
    throw new Error("Wrong value");
  },
  function(err) {
    if ( (err instanceof Error) && /value/.test(err) ) {
      return true;
    }
  },
  "unexpected error"
);
```